# How to set an initial value for my object in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am still pretty new to Rails and am working on a basic app and have run into a problem, which I can't seem to get around, sorry if this question has already been answered, but searching didn't yield me any results.

Basically I am creating an app that catalogues all of someones's clothes, Now the main page is the index page of everything they have logged, and each picture is linked to the show page where more information is revealed. I want to use AJAX to bring that show page to the side of the main index page. I am working off of another tutorial to figure this out but have run into a problem. On the initial load of my index page, I need to define a variable for that show page so that it can be rendered using a partial, but I can't use find(params[:id]) since the user hasn't selected anything yet. So my question is how do I set that initial value to either just the first item in the catalogue or not have anything appear, and then when someone does click the link, the sidebar shows the more detailed description of the piece of clothing.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you can post some relevant code, you are likely to get much more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have some luck working with the ruby gem 'PJAX'. [Here is a screen cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/294-playing-with-pjax) showing you how to get that AJAX sidebar you want. Good luck

Comment: Yeah, using that tutorial I figured out what I wanted to do. Thanks a lot for the link.

Answer (score 1):

```
@object = params[:id] ? MyModel.find(params[:id]) : MyModel.first
```

But I think there's some problem with design of application.

Comment: Maybe, I want on the initial load of the page for the sidebar to be blank, then when someone clicks a piece, that piece to appear in the sidebar. What is happening right now is that the sidebar is already trying to display something on the first load, and since the user hasn't selected anything, its not working. I might need to approach this differently

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you can just print the container element as normal, but leave it empty when the page is generated. Optionally, hide it via CSS. Then, when you load its content with AJAX, set it to visible or just populate it as normal.

Alternatively, if you really want to set it to the first item in the catalog (or in any `ActiveRecord`) you can use `.first` e.g. `Products.first`, and use that value to populate its initial contents.

Comment: I don't think it has to do with CSS, more so than how I have defined it in the controller. In the controller its @clothitem = Clothitem.find(params[:id]), I've tried messing around with if statements to get it to work, it might be the way I am approaching it.

Comment: Use of CSS is just one solution, it sounds like you're interested in megas's answer.